# Sketch or Axure?

Tags: prototype

I am trying to decide which prototyping tool to concentrate on, Sketch or Axure.  I have predominantly been using Axure but Sketch seems to be gaining popularity.

Answer (score 4):

Its simple.

Two basic stages of product design process are

1. **Low/High fidelity prototyping (Mainly UX)** - Used to test with people and ensure there is nothing missing out in the prototype or If something needs to be changed
2. **Final Visual Design (Mainly UI)** - One the requirements have been freezed, prototype been tested, you might shift to Sketch and detail out the designs. *SKETCH is a replacement for Photoshop not Axure*. For visual design, not prototyping (Although you can make a low-fi prototype using Marvel/Invision)

There are several plugins on Sketch which will make yours and your developers life very easy. So **go for the combo of both, or Just go for Sketch but with a catch that you'll not be able to make a high-fi prototype with it.**

Comment: I would like to add that Sketch is a vector based tool for creating wireframes and screens, in which you can export to tools such as Axure to generate clickable prototypes. From my experience so far, Axure is the top tool prototyping since it has advanced features such as variables to store state. This allows for advanced interactions showing realistic screens based on user input.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch is for wireframe, visual design and vector design.

Axure is for wireframe, design and **clickable prototype.**

Choose based on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I use both. Sketch for designs. Axure for prototyping.